# Downgrade PHP 7.3.2 to PHP 5.4 CentOS 7.6

Tags: php, centos-7, downgrade

How can i Downgrade PHP 7.3.2 to PHP 5.4 on CentOS 7.6?
I've tried this :

```
service httpd stop

sudo yum-config-manager --enable remi-php54
sudo yum-config-manager --disable remi-php73

sudo yum -y downgrade php php-cli php-fpm php-mysqlnd php-zip php-devel php-gd php-mcrypt php-mbstring php-curl php-xml php-pear php-bcmath php-json

sudo yum -y --enablerepo=remi-php54 install php-xml php-soap php-xmlrpc php-mbstring php-json php-gd php-mcrypt
```

But does not work & i am still on php 7.3.2.
How can i do that?

Comment: Duplicate of another question on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54681780/downgrade-php-7-3-2-to-php-5-4-centos-7-6

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has been cross posted to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500523/downgrade-php-7-3-2-to-php-5-4-centos-7-6